# Справка по gulp-replace на русском

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, gulp

Нашел справку [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace). Там же приведен код. Только не приведены результаты выполнения программ. Подскажите что делает gulp-replace.

1.

```
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

function replaceTemplate() {
  return src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('bar', 'foo'))
    .pipe(dest('build/'));
};

// or replace multiple strings
function replaceTemplate() {
  return src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('bar', 'foo'))
    .pipe(replace('baz', 'fuz'))
    .pipe(dest('build/'));
};

exports.replaceTemplate = replaceTemplate;
```

2. 

```
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

function replaceTemplate() {
  return src(['file.txt'])
      // See https://mdn.io/string.replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter
      .pipe(replace(/foo(.{3})/g, '$1foo'))
      .pipe(dest('build/'));
};

exports.replaceTemplate = replaceTemplate;
```

и т.д.

Comment: а зачем именно `на русском`?

Comment: @PeterKolosov обновил вопрос.

Comment: `что делает gulp-replace` возвращает функцию `replace`. А та, в свою очередь, может менять строку на строку... Может применяться несколько раз... Может работать и с регулярными выражениями...